# Hacer cast de apps completas

Tags: java, android, chrome

He visto que hay bastante código en internet para agregar la funcionalidad de cast a una app de Android. No obstante, todos ellos sirven para hacer cast de contenido multimedia, pero a mi me gustaría castear la app completa (es decir, que se vea en la televisión la app tal cual está). Por ello, querría saber si esto es posible y, de ser así, cómo se podría hacer.

Answer (score 1):

No se si te entendí muy bien, pero mírate este paquete (CastRemoteDisplay-Android   ) de la documentación oficial de android.
Paquete: https://github.com/googlecast/CastRemoteDisplay-android
Documentación: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Programaticamente puedes hacer uso del SDK Google Cast

https://developers.google.com/cast/

Aquí puedes ver ejemplos de implementación.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads

---

Una forma no programatica, es usar un Chromecast

https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=es

https://support.google.com/chromecastbuiltin/answer/6059461?hl=en